# Magento 2: Create product using rest API image upload not working

Tags: rest-api, image-upload, create-product, magento2.4.0

I have creating product using rest API but image upload not working.

**API:** baseurl/rest/V1/products

**Method:** POST

**Body:**

```
{
  "product": {
    "sku": "info",
    "name": "Info",
    "attribute_set_id": 4,
    "price": 1000,
    "status": 1,
    "custom_attributes": [
        {
            "attribute_code": "category_ids",
            "value": ["41","42","43"]
        },      
        {
          "attribute_code": "description",
          "value": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
        },      
        {
            "attribute_code": "image",
            "value": "image1.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "thumbnail",
            "value": "image2.jpg"
        },
        {
            "attribute_code": "small_image",
            "value": "image12.jpg"
        }
    ],
    "visibility": 4,
    "type_id": "simple",
    "weight": 1,
        "extension_attributes": {
            "stock_item": {
                "qty": "110",
                "is_in_stock": true
            }
        }
    },
    "saveOptions": true
}
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **base64_encoded_data** is missing, once check with that.
and check format of all images that are used.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using the Magento 2 REST API. Up to Magento 2.2 REST API only supports single object calls at a given time for image calls. You need to call multiple calls for multiple images.

if you still wanted to upload multiple images, you can do it by calling that function in the looping structure.